# Is command injection using a valid file path possible?

Tags: python, injection, command-line

My question is theoretical, and not bound to python - but for the sake of simplicity, I'll use Python code snippet.

Let's assume I have the following code:

```
import os
import sys

if os.path.exist(sys.argv[1]):
    os.system(f"echo {sys.argv[1]}")
```

Is there a way to do a command injection attack in the scenario when the unsanitized input is a path to a valid file?

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: Either of them interseting

Comment: How is this related to RE?

Comment: Also yes. It can lead to code execution [example](https://imgur.com/9eRFeJY)

Comment: @sudhackar sorry, this is not code execution. the lol executable in your example is executed by the shell, even before python runs.  The first correct example that comes to mind is a file with a name like "abcde;ls" where ls will be executed.

Comment: @ws you can see that I have escaped the string with ' before the ` [here](https://i.imgur.com/Dh5cuM7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On GNU/Linux, `system` passes any arguments to `/bin/sh -c "<command>"`. Any shell metacharacters  (e.g. `&`, `|`, `` ` ``, `$`, `;` etc.) in the command will be interpreted. So,  commands can be run using `` `command` `` or `$(command)` to use a subshell, or with other logic.

If a file has those characters, commands could be run:

```
$ ls itworks
$ touch '$(touch itworks)'
$ ./myscript.py '$(touch itworks)'
$ ls itworks
itworks
```

Since the file exists, it will be passed to `system`, and any nested commands executed. You may be limited in what commands and arguments can be passed, since `/` cannot be used in the filename.